# vosk transcription not loading, excessively long loading time that does not conclude

Tags: python, sample-rate, vosk, automatic-speech-recognition

I'm trying to do ASR speech to text transcription using the VOSK API, I have downloaded all the required models and and imported the required modules however my transcription simply does not load
here is my code below

```
from vosk import Model, KaldiRecognizer
import os
import queue
import vosk
import sys
import json
import wave 
model_dir="data/raw/vosk-model-small-en-us-0.15"
model = vosk.Model(model_dir)
# For a smaller download size, use model = Model(model_name="vosk-model-small-en-us-0.15")
#with wave.open("Audio_Files/EN/checkin.wav") as wf:
with wave.open("Audio_Files/EN/checkin.wav") as wf:
    assert wf.getnchannels() == 1, "must be a mono wav"
    assert wf.getsampwidth() == 2, "must be a 16bit wav"
    assert wf.getcomptype() == "NONE", "must be PCM data"

    rec = vosk.KaldiRecognizer(model, wf.getframerate())
    while True:
        data = wf.readframes(4000)
        if rec.AcceptWaveform(data):
            res = json.loads(rec.Result())
            print(res["text"])
```

it has been like this for 40 minutes
[image: vosk code cell]